# Cypress - using select() method with {scrollBehavior: 'center'}

Tags: testing, select, scroll, cypress, e2e

Website i am testing uses fixed menu, so i need to use `{scrollBehavior: 'center'}` setting for `click` methods, to avoid getting error saying that element i want to interact with is covered by my menu.

Same problem occurs with `<select>` elements i want to interact with, but it seems that setting `{scrollBehavior: 'center'}` does not work for `select()` method. I checked docs and in this mettod options param there is indeed no `scrollBehavior` setting. Is there any way to solve that problem?

I also tried using something like this, to scroll the page down, so element is no longer covered, but it had no effect.

```
cy.get('select')
    .scrollIntoView({offset: {top: 600, left: 0}})
    .select(someValue);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there global `scrollBehaviour` setting that can be set in `cypress.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost/spoke9/spoke-and-chain-testing/web/',
    scrollBehavior: 'nearest'
  }
};
```

Setting it to `nearest` solved this problem.

Answer (score 2):

One way round the problem is to set the viewport very large at the start of the test, so that everything is in view already. The [default](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/viewport#Default-sizing) of 1000x600 is not very realistic IMO.

For example, to match the monitor

```js
cy.viewport(3000,2000)
```

Also `.scrollIntoView()` is dependent of the element having a parent with a scrollable region. It can also be blocked by flexbox CSS settings.

Comment: Can you expand of having parent with scrollable region?

Comment: Cypress must be able to find a containing ancestor element that has the ability to scroll, which generally means it has CSS `overflow: scroll` or `overflow: auto` [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)